# Why admin url is not found running from JS?

Tags: laravel

In the routes/web.php of laravel 5.8 app I have defined :

```
Route::get('/adminPayConsultantInvoice/{invoice_id}', 'Server\AdminStripeController@payConsultantInvoice')->name('admin.pay-consultant-invoice');
```

but running from Javsscript :

```
   document.location='adminPayConsultantInvoice/'+invoice_id
```

I got 404 error
in output of

```
 php artisan route:list
```

I see

```
|        | GET|HEAD                               | adminPayConsultantInvoice/{invoice_id}            | admin.pay-consultant-invoice    | App\Http\Controllers\Server\AdminStripeController@payConsultantInvoice              | web,checkLocale       |
```

I do not see why I have this errir and how it can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried this

```
document.location="{{url('')}}/adminPayConsultantInvoice/"+invoice_id
```

It works fine for me always

Comment: No it does not work for me. Maybe some misspelling? But I do not see it

Comment: First check manually from any browser like `https:\\your_project_name/adminPayConsultantInvoice/1`